# How to obtain images in the head?

Tags: graphics, header-footer

How can I obtain and head like this, with images in it till the limit of the paper, and with a gradient similar to the image?

[image]

I have used `fancyhdr` package any times, but... in a very simple way with only text (Right Center or Left).

Comment: `\includegraphics` can also be used in the header.

Comment: I usually use the `eso-pic`package to position images in the outmost positions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution with `mdframed`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\let\oldheadrule\headrule
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\vskip-3\baselineskip\oldheadrule}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{%
\begin{mdframed}[%
    innertopmargin=0pt,
    innerbottommargin=0pt,
    innerleftmargin=0pt,
    tikzsetting={shade,left color=blue!50,right color=blue!10}
    ]
\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{example-image-a}\hfill\raisebox{.3\baselineskip}{\leftmark}
\end{mdframed}%
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{test}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would use TikZ and an environment which doesn't affect other typeset material in the header. It can be achived by the `pgfinterruptboundingbox` environment, then an object has width of 0 pt and height of 0 pt to the surrounding typeset material. I enclose an example as a starting point.

**Edit:** Next, I wrapped it all in the `scope` environment to move it all to the left margin of the paper. I changed twice `\textwidth` to `\paperwidth`. I usually use absolute positioning offered by TikZ, well, I wished to give `scope` a chance.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor,tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}\pagestyle{fancy}\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\def\mysquare{1cm}
\colorlet{myblue}{blue}
\fancyhead[L]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\begin{scope}[xshift=-1in-\hoffset-\oddsidemargin]
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\shade[fill=yellow, anchor=west, left color=myblue, right color=myblue!10, xshift=\mysquare] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth-\mysquare,\mysquare);
\node[minimum width=\mysquare, minimum height=\mysquare, draw, align=center, font=\bfseries\color{white}, fill=myblue, anchor=south west] at (0,0) (leftside) {MM\\O};
\node[font=\bfseries, anchor=east] at (\paperwidth,0.5\mysquare) {\leftmark\hspace{3mm}\thesection\hspace*{6mm}};
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}%
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}% End of \fancyhead...
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
\markboth{#1}{}}
\section{Enfriamiento simulado}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: ok, I use pstricks, but... it´s similar! Thank you, @malipivo